# Fowles, Introduction to Modern Optics 2nd edition, Problem 2.20

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

**My main concern is:**

How do I go from \begin{equation}\alpha = \sin^{-1} \sqrt{(n_1^2-n_2^2)/n_1^2}\end{equation} to \begin{equation}\alpha = \sin^{-1} \sqrt{n_1^2-n_2^2}?\end{equation}I could just assume $n_1 = 1$, but I don't think that's a fair assumption.

**More information :**

> Show that the acceptance angle $\alpha$ for a glass-fiber waveguide is given by
>   \begin{equation}
> \alpha = \sin^{-1} \sqrt{n_1^2-n_2^2}
> \end{equation}
>   where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the indices of refraction of the fiber and the cladding material, respectively, and the external medium is air, $n_0 = 1$.

My attempt is in this image:

> [image]

Comment: Hi TechMaster100; we prefer that you don't post formulas as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

Comment: Don't blindly apply that equation for critical angle. What is the medium where $\alpha$ is the optical angle?